# Unital amenable Banach algebras which is a proper two sided ideal in its second dual

Tags: harmonic-analysis, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras, amenability

I need some examples of  "unital amenable Banach algebras which is a proper two sided ideal in its second dual".

Comment: I think for any compact Hausdorff space $\Omega$, the space of continuous functions on $\Omega$, $C(\Omega)$ is a unital nuclear(amenable) $C^*$-Banach algebra. But I don't know about dimension of it and about being ideal in its second dual.